# Cisco Anyconnect: Vpn establishment capability from a remote desktop is disabled

Tags: windows-7, cisco, remote-desktop, rdp, anyconnect

I need to run Cisco AnnyConnect from a VM in a data center.  When I run it I get this message:

*Vpn establishment capability from a remote desktop is disabled*

Can this be turned off?  I saw some posts about it, but required downloading Cisco software with an account, which I do not have.  The VPN software is from a client I work for.

Comment: Related link http://joaodev.wordpress.com/2013/08/29/bypassing-cisco-anyconnects-profile-settings/

Comment: I have a Windows 10 Host and Windows 10 Hyper-V VM so that i can connect to customer VPN's without killing my connectivity. I find that i get this message if i use "Enhanced Session", so i turn that off, connect and turn it back on again and it works fine. Go Figure.

Answer (score 16):

I've found a workaround for this problem when there is no access to VPN server settings:

- set up [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/)
- disconnect RDP
- connect via Teamviewer
- connect to VPN in remote session
- disconnect Teamviewer
- connect via RDP
- continue working as used to

Comment: splashtop also work.  NOTE: once VPN connection kicks in, it may drop the splashtop connection

Comment: Best answer IMO for solving the issue in the shortest amount of steps.

Comment: Vadzim opened up my eyes to see what was the problem, acessed my support VM via console and now I could access the VPN, great!

Answer (score 11):

It really depends on the version you are using, but nowadays this is done by creating an `AnyConnect Client Profile` on the ASA itself.

By default the policy will be set to `LocalUsersOnly` and you need to change it to `AllowRemoteUsers`.

You'll need access to the ASA though (ASDM) in order to do this.

The steps would be:

1. Log into the ASDM
2. Go to Configuration, Remote Access VPN, Anyconnect Client Profile
3. Click Add and create a new profile and choose the Group Policy it should apply to
4. Click OK, and then at the Profile screen click "Apply" at the bottom (important)
5. Now edit the profile, and you should see under the Preferences, Windows VPN Establishment you can select "AllowRemoteUsers" and hit OK
6. Apply once more and then save/writemem
7. That's it, RDP and try again

[image: ASA config]

If you don't have access to the ASA, the best I can suggest is to use a different type of remote connection like VNC or Teamviewer as they will allow you to use the VPN.

Comment: No, we don't own the VPN, our client does, and so it wont likely happen.

Comment: You need to VPN in to the client's network from your VM or from their VM to your network?  I'm guessing the former since you said they own the VPN, but still a little lost on that part.  Regardless, since it's a VM maybe you can gain access to the console through the vmware client or hyper-v manager and log in on the "console".  That would work as well.  Other than that...you might simply be out of luck (again short of vnc/teamviewer/logmein/etc.)

Comment: What does ASA mean, and is it available when one simply downloads "Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client" from a remote VPN's web portal? I don't see anything called "ADSM" on my Start Menu...

Comment: I see the Cisco website proposes a demo download of ASDM. Does anyone know whether the demo supports this feature?

Answer (score 10):

Connect to your computer via RDP.
Create connect.dat file as following, finishing it with extra empty line (must-have requirement, sic!):

```
connect your-VPN-server-here
your-username-here
your-password-here
```

Then create connect.cmd file as following

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%G in ('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq tasklist.exe" /NH') do SET RDP_SESSION=%%G
Rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation
tscon.exe %RDP_SESSION% /dest:console
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpncli.exe" -s <connect.dat
```

Correct the path to vpncli.exe if necessary. Then terminate VPN UI process (it shouldn't be loaded into memory) and start our CMD file as a local admin.

If you don't mind, full note is here http://windowsasusual.blogspot.ru/2016/10/cisco-anyconnect-vpn-and-remote-desktop.html

Comment: `connect.dat` also must have an absolute path e.g.: "C:\Users\yourname\Desktop\connect.dat". `connect.dat` can add other commands like `y/n`(yes/no). `connect.cmd` add to last line `pause` to debug. to disconnect vpn `vpncli.exe disconnect`. `connect.cmd` should run as **admin**.

Answer (score 8):

I found a solution to make it work.  My work laptop need to be connected to a vpn with cisco any connect . And I wanted to connect to my work laptop using remote desktop to have a better experience with my home PC mouse and keyboard and a bigger screen.

I had this error after the VPN was connecting: Vpn establishment capability from a remote desktop is disabled.

**Start the VPN on the laptop first then use RDP**

I could solve this issue by starting the VPN connection on my laptop first.  Once the connection is established, I logged on with remote desktop on my laptod and its working!

Hope this helps

Comment: I was after the same work/home setup you were, and didn't think to try this. It works perfectly though. Thanks.

Comment: If VNP connection interrupts on holidays this wouldn't help until you move to the workplace.

Comment: This wouldn't work if split tunneling isn't enabled and my employer's AnyConnect VPN server doesn't seem to allow that to be set on the client.

Answer (score 4):

The fix for this issue is start the VPN session using the "Basic mode" (disabling the "Enhanced session" option). It worked for me. Look this post:

https://foxdeploy.com/2015/11/20/solved-cisco-anyconnect-session-ended-error/

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault! Answers need to be able to stand alone. Please include relevant information in your post.

Comment: That's for Hyper-V only, and not for the case when you actually use RDP.